# tests fail when injecting a class with decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, inversifyjs

This is likely an environment issue on my end, but I'm having problems testing injected classes that use decorators.

Am hoping someone can see what I'm missing.

Note: that when I run the code, it runs fine. The error only occurs when running jest tests. I have a full test suite that works fine. The test in question that fails passes when I remove the decorator annotation and no longer have the class extend `EventEmitter`.

I also use `ts-node` to run the code. I use `ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/jest src/event-emitter-inversify/__tests__/event-emitter-inversify.test.ts`

I'm not sure why the tests fail and the run succeeds.

I consistently see the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of null` in my tests.

Here is the setup.

**event-emitter-inversify.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import { ContainerModule, decorate, injectable, interfaces } from 'inversify';

decorate(injectable(), EventEmitter);

@injectable()
export class EventEmitterChild extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  greet() {
    console.log('hello world.');
  }
}

export const EventEmitterModule = new ContainerModule(
  (bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
    bind<EventEmitterChild>('EventEmitterChild').to(EventEmitterChild).inSingletonScope();
  }
);
```

**event-emitter-inversify-dependent.ts**

```
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import { EventEmitterChild } from './event-emitter-inversify';

@injectable()
export class EventEmitterDependent {
  constructor(@inject('EventEmitterChild') private readonly _eventEmitterChild: EventEmitterChild) {
  }

  run() {
    this._eventEmitterChild.greet();
  }
}
```

**run.ts  (this runs fine!)**

```
import { Container } from 'inversify';

import { EventEmitterChild, EventEmitterModule } from './event-emiiter-inversify';
import { EventEmitterDependent } from './event-emitter-inversify-dependent';

const referenceContainer = new Container();

referenceContainer.load(EventEmitterModule);

const eventEmitterChild = referenceContainer.get<EventEmitterChild>('EventEmitterChild');
eventEmitterChild.greet();

const eventEmitterDependent = referenceContainer.get<EventEmitterDependent>('EventEmitterDependent');

eventEmitterDependent.run();
```

**event-emitter-inversify.test.ts (this fails)**

```
import { Container } from 'inversify';

import { EventEmitterChild, EventEmitterModule } from '../event-emitter-inversify';

describe('EventEmitter test', () => {
  const container: Container = new Container();

  beforeAll(async () => {
    container.load(EventEmitterModule);
  });

  test('get EventEmitterChild from container', () => {
    const eventEmitterChild = container.get<EventEmitterChild>('EventEmitterChild');

    expect(eventEmitterChild).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I run the test with:

```
ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/jest src/event-emitter-inversify/__tests__/event-emitter-inversify.test.ts
```

And it fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of null
```

**stacktrace**

```
  at getClassPropsAsTargets (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/reflection_utils.js:82:75)
  at getClassPropsAsTargets (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/reflection_utils.js:84:27)
  at getClassPropsAsTargets (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/reflection_utils.js:84:27)
  at getTargets (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/reflection_utils.js:28:27)
  at Object.getDependencies (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/reflection_utils.js:12:19)
  at node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/planner.js:106:51
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at _createSubRequests (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/planner.js:94:20)
  at Object.plan (node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/planner.js:136:9)
  at node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:318:37
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @lostdorje, it's been a while – were you able to solve this issue and do you remember the solution? I'm having a similar issue without _ts-node_, my error is `Missing required @injectable annotation in:`.